# Simple MySql or MySqli Class

Tags: php, object-oriented, comparative-review, mysqli

Which one of these methods is better/safer to use? And what benefits could I get using one or other?

### Simple mysqli:

#### connection.php

```
$DBServer = "localhost";
$DBPort = "3306";
$DBUser = "root";
$DBPass = "";
$DBName = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName, $DBPort);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Database connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR;
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

#### index.php

```
include_once("connection.php");

$l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['l_name']);

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE lname='".$l_name."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name'].'<br>';
}
```

### mysqli with class:

#### connection.php

```
class Connect
{

    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'root';
    var $pass = '';
    var $db = 'test';
    var $con;

    function connect() {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if (!$con) {
            //die('Could not connect to database!');
        } else {
            $this->con = $con; //echo 'Connection established!';
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($this->con,"utf8");

        return $this->con;

    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

}
```

#### index.php

```
include_once("connection.php");

$con = new Connect();
$con->connect();

$l_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con->con, $_GET['l_name']);

$query = mysqli_query($con->con, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE lname='".$l_name."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['f_name'].' '.$row['l_name'].'<br>';
}
```

Can you review my code for security and best coding practices?

Comment: Your question title is not meant to address your concern, it is meant to describe what your code does.

Comment: FYI You should use parameterized queries: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/prevent-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications/

Comment: The answer will be "they're both unsafe".

Comment: The second one just adds no value, so it is useless. See [how to connect with mysqli properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect), then [how to query with mysqli properly](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) and finally [how to reduce the insane amount of code when you need to run a prepared query only once](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) (99% of time)

Comment: @JohnConde how can i fix that in simple mysqli example? And how can i test/hack it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use either - PDO is much more user-friendly and feature-rich.  Generally a class will be nicer to write code around, and now that we have PDO we don't need to write that class.  The following example is largely stolen from here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

```
$DBUser = "root";
$DBPass = "";
$DBName = "test";
$DBCharset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$DBServer;dbname=$DBName;charset=$DBCharset";
$DBOptions = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBOptions);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     // to avoid a potential credentials leak through a stack trace
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE lname = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_GET['l_name']]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "{$row['f_name']} {$row['l_name']}<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you editor for fixing my idiot mistakes in my hasty response

Comment: I took a liberty to fix some code mistakes and made your reasoning factually correct. JFYI, mysqli is never going to be deprecated, it's perfectly all right.

Comment: First a big thanks for your answer! However what would you suggest me to fix if i would want to keep simple mysqli example style?

Comment: @MaKR First a big thanks for your answer! However what would you suggest me to fix if i would want to keep simple mysqli example style?

Comment: The biggest issue with either solution is not using prepared statements.  Here is a great mysqli explanation, and early in the article the author links to a class example he has written.  At the end he also links to articles on pros and cons of both.  I would suggest using a class.  https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection